# performance of MATLAB calculation vs MEX programing

Tags: matlab, mex

I am making a statistic analyzer

I have around 100+- matrices of 2*30,000
and for each row i need to check and sum:

```
 * get number of values greater then 0 for each row
 * get the sum of values for each row
```

Now for the logic question

what is faster and better programming,

MEX:

```
going in for loops for each row over all matrices
inside a for over all the matrices
```

MATLAB:

```
using matrix calculating to get the sum of each row
and ready function to get the number of non zero matrices at each row?
```

P.S
 any one can help me with the matlab code idea? I am c programmer, how to get the number of matrices where `value == 0`

Comment: Why don't you try coding both yourself and seeing which one is faster?  However, for what you're asking, I would stick with using the MATLAB functions.  `sum` and its related brethren all essentially call LAPACK functions or variants of them and LAPACK is very optimized FORTRAN code.  It's basically as fast as you'll ever get it.

Comment: the speed i can check myself. i was asking for your guys experience if it is good programming or not

Comment: Very easy Matlab: `sum_of_rows = sum(A,2);` `num_values_gt_0_rows = sum(A>0,2);`. You matrices aren't very big. Just do it in Matlab.

Comment: If you want a Code Review on code that you wrote, there's a dedicated StackExchange website for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  Only post there if you have actually written the code and would like feedback.  However, horchler pretty much showed you how you'd do it in MATLAB for one matrix.  Depending on how your data is set up, you'll either have to loop or stack all of the matrices into a 3D matrix and operate that way.

Comment: thx guys, writing both options now and will post the speed results here
i dont see option to close this post...

Comment: @JohnnyF - You don't have to.  Post your answer and you can mark your answer as accepted.  I'm actually quite curious to see which one is faster.

Comment: Good programming in Matlab means most of the time programming in Matlab. ;-)